# in listview android items repeating

Tags: android

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService("layout_inflater");

    if (convertView != null) {
        return convertView;
    }

    list = new View(this.mContext);
    list = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowsset, null);
    imageView = (ImageView) list.findViewById(R.id.pic1);
    textView1 = (TextView) list.findViewById(R.id.det2);
    textView2 = (TextView) list.findViewById(R.id.kite1);
    textView1.setText(this.web[position]);
    textView2.setText(this.web1[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(this.Imageid[position]);

    return list;
}
```

Comment: add your activity/fragment code also, "with proper formatting"

Comment: Simplest solution is to remove the `if (convertView != null) { return convertView; }` block. You're not really doing that correctly. Consult the example you're following again.

Comment: what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder viewHolder;
final View result;
if (convertView == null) {

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowsset, parent, false);
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic1);
    textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.det2);
    textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.kite1); 

    result=convertView;
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    result=convertView;
}

viewHolder.textView1.setText(this.web[position]);
viewHolder.textView2.setText(this.web1[position]);
viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(this.Imageid[position]);

// Return the completed view to render on screen
return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Please this line mention in your adapter's constructor
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowsset, null);
    imageView = (ImageView) list.findViewById(R.id.pic1);
    textView1 = (TextView) list.findViewById(R.id.det2);
    textView2 = (TextView) list.findViewById(R.id.kite1);
    textView1.setText(web[position]);
    textView2.setText(web1[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

Hope this will work...